# JS, как указать логической конструкции if else сравнивать значение с ключом массива

Tags: javascript, if

как указать логической конструкции `if else` сравнивать число не со значением в переменной массива ("двенадцать") а с ключом переменной массива (12), то есть, чтобы он как и прежде брал значение из массива, но при этом сравнивал его с ключом, а не со значением прикрепленным к ключу

[image]

Comment: Скажите что Вам надо, тогда проще будет.

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: первый индекс массива - 0. Просто проверяйте `[нужное_число + 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var a = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 12: "twelve", 20: "twenty" };
if (12 in a)
  console.log(a[12]);
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно